# ImagePicker image not diplayed after selection /Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, uiimagepickercontroller

Used ImagePicker to select an image in gallery. Worked but no image is desplayed.
ERROR : Unhandled Exception: type 'XFile' is not a subtype of type 'File' in type cast

Below my code :

```
class _RegisterScreenState extends State {
File image;
String imgUrl;
final imagePicker = ImagePicker();

Future getImage() async {

File img = await imagePicker.pickImage(
source: ImageSource.gallery);
setState(() {
image = img as File;
});
}

child: CircleAvatar(
radius: 60,
backgroundColor: Colors.white,
backgroundImage: image != null
? Image.file(image)
: NetworkImage(
"https://cdn-icons-png.flaticon.com/512/1177/1177568.png"),
),
```

ERROR : Unhandled Exception: type 'XFile' is not a subtype of type 'File' in type cast

I am on :

```
version: 1.0.0+1
environment:
sdk: ">=2.7.0 <3.0.0"
image_picker: ^0.8.4+2
path_provider: ^2.0.5
```

Answer (score 2):

I too faced this error. I solved this by:

```
File myImage;
Future getImage() async {
   File img = await ImagePicker.pickImage(source: ImageSource.gallery);      
   setState(() {
      myImage = File(img.path);
   });
}
```

Comment: image = File(img.path) does not work for me: astract class cannot be instantiated.

Comment: tried your code : File img = await imagePicker.pickImage(source: ImageSource.gallery); a value type XFile can't be assigned to a variable of type File

Comment: @213Lord This is strange it worked for me. Try changing it to   myImage = File(img.path.toString());

Answer (score 0):

Using image_picker: ^0.7.4 and try:

```
  ImagePicker imagePicker = ImagePicker();
  final image = await imagePicker.getImage(source: ImageSource.gallery);
```

You will get the photo by using image.path.

Comment: Thank you for your help. I test 0.7.4, but I have an issue with File(img.path) : astract class cannot be instantiated.

class _RegisterScreenState extends State<RegisterScreen> {
  File image;
  String imgUrl;
  final imagePicker = ImagePicker();
  

  Future getImage() async {
    var img = await imagePicker.getImage(source: ImageSource.gallery);
    setState(() {
      
      image = File(img.path);
    });
  }